# Is this in-scope? Can companies use SO for their helpdesk?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

So... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57085602/8954291). I really don't even know where to start. The OP for the question apparently was referred here by another company for their vendor-specific problems. Is this even remotely in scope, is it an example of abuse, or what?

Comment: Do you know they were referred here rather than just coming here on their own? If they've been referred, we'll reach out to the company about it to be sure their guidance on when to ask here is correct.

Comment: OP says that "...SagePay directed me here..." so I assume they were referred.

Comment: The help pages link to SO after every other option in a section for dev help. https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/partners-and-developers-support That's not really what I'd call a referral but the link needs some context.

Comment: @Catija If you go to Support -> Business Support (or Partners & Developers) -> Online -> Support forum, you get linked straight to [so]. That seems quite misleading. Also, if you Google "sagepay support forum", that's the first result. There's also no indication on [that page](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum) about what type of content is appropriate to be asked here (apart from linking to "about").

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Clearly off topic, and the OP clearly knows it is.  So, DV, VTC and move on

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is more about whether a company can do this:

[image]

They link to a page of all questions tagged sagepay, which seems fine to me.  They still have their own information on their own page.  Although if it were me, I'd point out that that should be a developer-issue link, and maybe also link to MCVE.